# Why my PHP PDO LOCK TABLE for mysql table is not working for concurrency operation?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, concurrency

I have two problems in my code,

```
$q="call transactionSP()";
$resLock = $this->db->beginTransaction();//PDO beginTransaction
$resLock = $this->db->LockExec("LOCK TABLES t_transaction WRITE");//PDO exec
sleep(10);
$res=$this->db->insert($q);//PDO query
$resUnlock = $this->db->LockExec("UNLOCK TABLES");//PDO exec
$resLock = $this->db->commitTransaction();//PDO commit
```

**Problem 1:** Here t_transaction is not locked while Request1 is executing sleep(10).I run Request2 which reads the data from the table while Request1 is executing sleep(10), which confirms that t_transaction is not locked. Why the LOCK TABLE is not locking the table? How do i get the table locked?

**Problem 2:**
code inside my stored procedure transactionSP() which is called from the above code:

```
INSERT INTO t_transaction(TransactionType,UserID,Amount,OpeningBalance,ClosingBalance,CreatedBy) VALUES(inTransactionType,inUserID,inAmount,(SELECT t.ClosingBalance FROM t_transaction t WHERE t.UserID=inUserID ORDER BY t.CreatedDate DESC,t.TransactionID DESC LIMIT 1),(SELECT t.ClosingBalance FROM t_transaction t WHERE t.UserID=inUserID ORDER BY t.CreatedDate DESC,t.TransactionID DESC LIMIT 1)+inAmount,inUserID);
```

Here I assumed INSERT query should lock the t_transaction table while inserting the record. But when Request1&Request2 are executing at the same time both request executing SELECT query in first second and then INSERT in the next second. Why is it?. SELECT which I wrote inside INSERT also should be part of the INSERT lock, right? which means Request1&Request2 cannot do SELECT at the same seconds, isn't it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You're not locking the table until AFTER `sleep(10)`. So Request2 should be able to read the table while Request1 is sleeping.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem outside of PHP, by just executing queries from the `mysql` CLI client?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried from Phpmyadmin and MySQL workbench ( I am not good in CLI :) ). Phpmyadmin is not locking the table  like my PHP code. But MySQL workbench does locks.

Comment: In PhpMyAdmin, each query creates a new database connection, so you can't have a transaction across multiple queries. It looks like you're using your own database class, make sure it doesn't open a new connection for each operation.

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar. Your response helped me on time. Now it is resolved.